# Can not trace the packets to a specific gateway ip

Tags: networking, routing, wireshark, gateway, traceroute

I try to make the OSX host-A to be a specific gateway for a Linux host-B. The default gateway entry of B has been deleted and add a specific gateway as below. Note: `98.136.144.138` is the ip address of domain name of "search.yahoo.com". Host-A can reach search.yahoo.com normally. ip of A is `10.192.29.246` and ip of B is `10.192.13.160`.

[image]

When host-B browser refreshes the ip of `98.136.144.138`, the web page shows as expected. But the Wireshark can not capture any packets illustrating the packets from host-B reach the gateway host-A first and host-A routes these packets. Why the information does not show?

- The packets Wireshark captured in host-B as below. After I add specific route and refresh `98.136.144.138` of Yahoo Search in browser of host-B, packets below the line in picture turn up. But no info upon packets to specific gateway(host-A). And how to get the packets to a gateway if necessary?

[image]

- The returns of command `traceroute 98.136.144.138`in host-B as below. And why the fist line is old default gateway 10.255.255.1 not specific gateway host-A. Host-A ip `10.192.29.246` even did not show .

[image]

If we can not trace or capture the data from host-B to the specific gateway(host-A) according to the routing table when browse the "Yahoo Search" page, how do we know whether it's really happened that host-B reach "Yahoo Search" page via host-A? The routing rules are on the routing table, but we need to really know that. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:** add the layer II information of Wireshark below.`10.192.26.24` is the host-B ip address now since restarted (But host-A is still `10.192.29.246`). The first packet is sent to MAC address `00:00:5e:00:01:02` which belongs to the deleted default gateway `10.192.0.1`. But how does it still be sent to deleted gateway? All following packets don't contain MAC address of host-A.
[image]

[image]

**Update:** And a diagram for illustrating my purpose.
[image]
I am not sure this is right? Today when I retried this, host-B could access to `98.136.144.138` at first and Wireshark captured some info about "redirect". This is real communication between host-A and host-B.
[image]

However, it was really weird after a while, host-B could not access to `98.136.144.138` anymore but Wireshark captured host-B did really send packets to host-A via layer of Ethernet II and not to original deleted default gateway.
[image]

Comment: What Linux kernel version is host B running? What's your full routing table (as shown by `ip -4 route` and `ip -4 rule`)? What's the point of hiding 10.x addresses?

Comment: @grawity The question just has been updated as your suggestion. The kernel version of host-B is `Linux admin-PC 4.16.0-kali2-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.16.16-2kali2 (2018-07-04) i686 GNU/Linux`. Please keep helping on this issue and let me know if any more information needed.

Comment: In response to the new question in the Updated section:  Please provide the output of: `ip route` and `ip address` on the Linux endpoint host.  This will help determine the configuration of the Linux host.

Answer (score 1):

Your tcpdump / wireshark display shows layer 3 (IP) addresses.  Communication with the gateway happens at layer 2 (Ethernet).

You should expand one (any one) of the packets below the red line, and compare the source and destination MAC addresses of the frame with the two hosts.  One will be the source host (host B), and the other should be the MAC address of the gateway (host A), if things are working correctly.

The source and destination IP address of the packet won't change as it passes through the network and routers, but the MAC address of the wrapping ethernet (or other layer 2) frame will be different for every leg of that trip.

With regard to the traceroute, you can probably look up a way to configure an OS-X system to send ICMP errors so that the OS-X host shows up in traceroute, but it isn't clear that that will further your fundamental goal.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I expanded these packets and check the info of Ethernet II but the MAC address of host-A does not appear.

Comment: I added a screenshot in the bottom of question. Please check it.

Comment: I see a new question in the edited section, which is great. I have no problems helping you understand what is going on, but I would like to point out that this is a different / additional question, and you'll need to elaborate / provide additional data to get an answer.  I'm not sure how this pattern fits into the StackExchange / SuperUser model.

Comment: Since the new updated question as you mentioned is based on the original, opening a new question must contain the original condition too.  I have added the `ip route` and `ip address` info at the bottom of question. Please update your answer if it's convenient for you. I do really appreciate for your help on this.

Comment: I think there must be something wrong! Considering what I had tried is make host-A to be a router exactly to routing packets to host-A's default gateway, but a router needs no less than 2 internet interface and host-A only has one. The reason why packets did not go to host-A is unsure. If packets go to host-A then these packets should not be routing, right?

Comment: What is your fundamental goal here?  Just to set up an OS-X system as a router?  To what ends?  Do you simply want to capture traffic silently?  What's your plan?

Comment: Yes, just make OS-X system be a router and just one NIC to receive and transfer. I am trying to dig deeply for the details.